# Awesome-WM - How to center a wibox.widget.textbox in a wibox.container?

Tags: lua, window-managers, awesome-wm

I would like to know how to center a `wibox.widget.textbox` in `wibox.container.background`, because I would like to center the text in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7dKf.png).

```
s.mytaglist = awful.widget.taglist {
    screen  = s,
    filter  = awful.widget.taglist.filter.all,
    buttons = tag_list_buttons,
    widget_template = {
        id = 'background_role',
        widget = wibox.container.background,
        forced_width = 40,
        {
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal,
            {
                id = 'text_role',
                widget = wibox.widget.textbox,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I have try to add `expand = "outside"` but that doesn't work. Also, I doesn't want to use a `wibox.container.margin`, because it's not precise enough.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [align](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.widget.textbox.html#wibox.widget.textbox.align) and [valign](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.widget.textbox.html#wibox.widget.textbox.valign) properties of the [textbox](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.widget.textbox.html) to `"center"` for horizontal and vertical center alignment.

Comment: Ok, so I have move `force_width` in the textbox properties and also set `aligne = "center"` . Now it work. Thank you.